# Julia: read many files in the working directory

Tags: julia

I just started learning Julia and I want to read many csv files in my directory. How can I do that?

My directory has the files below and I want to read in all files from trip_data_1 to trip_data_12.

"trip_data_1.csv" 
 "trip_data_10.csv"
 "trip_data_11.csv"
 "trip_data_12.csv"
 "trip_data_2.csv" 
 "trip_data_3.csv" 
 "trip_data_4.csv" 
 "trip_data_5.csv" 
 "trip_data_6.csv" 
 "trip_data_7.csv" 
 "trip_data_8.csv" 
 "trip_data_9.csv" 
 "trip_fare_1.csv" 
 "trip_fare_10.csv"
 "trip_fare_11.csv"
 "trip_fare_12.csv"
 "trip_fare_2.csv" 
 "trip_fare_3.csv" 
 "trip_fare_4.csv" 
 "trip_fare_5.csv" 
 "trip_fare_6.csv" 
 "trip_fare_7.csv" 
 "trip_fare_8.csv" 
 "trip_fare_9.csv"

This is what I have tried:

```
using DataFrames
df = readtable(filter!(r"^trip_data", readdir()))
```

But I get *MethodError: no method matching readtable(::Array{String,1})*

Comment: `filter!` (in this scenario) returns `Array{String, 1}`, i.e. a vector of all your file-names. But `readtable` can only read one file at a time, and so needs a `String` input. Solution? Just iterate over the output of your `filter!` operation with calls to `readtable`.

Comment: Thanks! That helps!

Answer (score 6):

I'm a big fan of `.` `broadcast`ing syntax in this type of situation.

I.e. `df = readtable.(filter(r"^trip_data", readdir()))` will give you an array of data frames (@avysk is correct that you probably want `filter` not `filter!`.

If you want one single data frame then the `mapreduce`option is good.

Or you can: `vcat(readtable.(filter(r"^trip_data", readdir()))`

***NB: All of these are general solutions to the problem, I have a function (method) that applies `f` to `x` and now I want to apply it to many instances, or an array, of `x`***

So if you get another error that indicates that you cannot apply a function directly to any array or collection, but you can to a single element, then `map`, `broadcast`/`.` & list comprehensions are your friends!

Comment: Nice approach with broadcasting! However, in case of "I need one dataframe" I think `mapreduce` (not `reduce(... map(...))`, though) is the best, since it doesn't duplicate the data in memory -- all other approaches first create a sequence of dataframes, which is kept in memory until the creation of the final result is done. On the other hand, `mapreduce` doesn't build intermediate sequence. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Nope, that's correct. The only reason I can think of to create an intermediate collection first is if you need to keep track of which file each row/frame originated from.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
reduce(vcat,  map(readtable, filter(r"^trip_data", readdir())))
```

Here `map` applies `readtable` to every filename matched by `filter` (you don't need `filter!` here) and joins all resulting dataframes together (`vcat`).

The same can be written with `mapreduce`:

```
mapreduce(readtable, vcat, filter(r"^trip_data", readdir()))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using Glob that I believe is more readable:

```
using CSV, Glob, DataFrames

files = glob("trip_data_*.csv")
dfs = CSV.read.(files)
```

As mentioned in another answer, `CSV.read.` (with the final dot) broadcasts over the `files` array, and creates an array of DataFrames. Therefore, the last line is equivalent to:

```
dfs = [CSV.read(file) for file in files]
```

Finally, if you want to concatenate all the files, you can simply do:

```
df = vcat(dfs...)
```

where the `...` is used to pass a variable number of arguments to a function.

Comment: Hello. I find this solution very easy and useful. How can one choose a different file directory?

Answer (score 3):

Another method (which moves concatenation to the input String level instead of DataFrame level) and uses `Iterators` package:

`readtable(IOBuffer(join(chain([drop((l for l in readlines(fn)),i>1?1:0) for (i,fn) in enumerate(filter!(r"^trip_data", readdir()))]...))))`

This may actually save some time and allocations (in my pet example it did), but it depends on the parameters of the input files.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do a simple

```
files = filter(r".csv$", readdir(path))
df = vcat([readtable(f) for f in files])
```

and as a follow up, I did the same with julia's `CSV.read(file)` and this is much slower. Actually not the reading part, but the sourcing part:

```
source = CSV.Source(file)
CSV.Read(source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing the answers above.  It seems that CSV.read will be deprecated. In addition it appears some users had problems [deleting rows from DataFrames](http://https:/https://discourse.julialang.org/t/delete-row-from-dataframe-incompatible-with-csv-jl/39835) when using CSV.read directly. This code posted [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/read-multiple-csv-files/43806/2) using CSV.File might also help.

```
using CSV, Glob, DataFrame  
folder = "d:/Data/Test/" 
files = glob("*.csv", folder) 
df3=DataFrame.(CSV.File.(files))
```